# Decryption in the Merkle-Hellman cryptosystem

Tags: cryptography

> In a Merkle-Hellman cryptosystem, plaintext message units are of length $3$ over the alphabet
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>   &A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&J&K&L&M&N&O \\
>  &0 &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8&9&10&11&12&13&14\\
> \end{array}
> $$
>   $$
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  &P&Q&R&S&T&U&V&W&X&Y&Z&\fbox{}&?&!&.&'&$&\\
>  &15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27&28&29&30&31\\
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> The following sequence of ciphertext message units is received.
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  &152472, 116116, 68546, 165420, 168261
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> The public key is
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{cccc}
> &24038, 29756, 34172,34286,38334,1824,18255,19723,143,17146\\
> &35366, 11204, 32395, 12958, 6479
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> and the secret key is $b=30966$, $m=47107$. Decrypt the message.

Myself and a classmate are struggling to do this exam question so we would really appreciate some help! :) Step-by-step if possible as we don't have any similar examples in our class notes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to write up an exam question? Does your instructor allow this? Also, the typical parameters use $q$ and $r$ for what you call $b$ and $m$, so I cannot tell them apart. Can you add the equations for encryption and decryption to be sure? Regards

Comment: @Amzoti the larger number is $q$ the smaller $r$, obviously, as $r$ must be invertible modulo $q$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the complete secret key, because the superincreasing sequence cannot be directly computed from the public key, even with known $b$ (multiplier) and $m$ (modulus); in our case $b^{-1} \pmod{m} = 6479$ But the Shamir paper [see here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.123.5840&rep=rep1&type=pdf) does give some ideas about that.

How I solved the message is by completely ignoring the private key components and by building (using the public key only) a table (using a programme of course) that computes the encrpytion of all 3 letter combinations; a programme can do that in fewer than a second easily, and then match the observed cipher values.

There is no randomisation, so we just have a public key block cipher with a very small blocksize of 15 bits. This yielded `FOR MUL A S TOL EN!` as the five plain blocks BTW.